# Import packages for service bus sas connection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, azureservicebus

I am trying to send messages to a queue. I have created below function to create the SAS Connection

```
def configureSASAuthentication (namespace: String, sasKeyName: String, sasKey: String, serviceBusRootUri: String): ServiceBusContract = { 
  val config = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(namespace, sasKeyName, sasKey, serviceBusRootUri) 
  val service: ServiceBusContract = ServiceBusService.create(config) 
  return service
}
```

I am not sure which packages I need to import. i am getting below error:

```
error: not found: type ServiceBusContract
error: not found: value ServiceBusConfiguration
error: not found: type ServiceBusContract
error: not found: value ServiceBusService
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Azure serivce bus classes. You should get them with the following assuming you have added the library to your project:

```
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.*;
```

You should of course, have Azure messaging service bus and azure core imported. You could add the following dependencies to your build.sbt if you don't have it already:

```
"com.azure" % "azure-core" % "1.13.0",
"com.azure" % "azure-messaging-servicebus" % "7.0.2"
```